# Always Encrypted with R2DBC

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I trying to save to a table with encrypted fields but I cannot find R2DBC support.

[Image of encrypted columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK9V5.png)

Found a similar question but without using R2DBC

[SQL Server Column Encryption using Azure Key Vault and Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56186470/sql-server-column-encryption-using-azure-key-vault-and-spring-boot)

JDBC documentation it explains how to do it but I did not find something similar for R2DBC

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-always-encrypted-with-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score -1):

Just for now, Azure SQL database doesn't support R2DBC.

Others have post the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/37811770-add-r2dbc-connection-url-to-azure-sql-server-conne):
[image]

We can continue to vote it then the product team could see it and may add this feature.

HTH.

Comment: Azure SQL is supported by R2DBC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-data-r2dbc-with-azure-sql-server